# How can I correct this error : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory' or one of its dependencies. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Tags: asp.net

I typed my url into my browser and had hoped to bring up my website, but instead I received this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I am looked in my web config and I looked at my solution, and in the /bin folder the dll is present. I even removed that dll and rebuilt my solution.

Not certain what to do next.

Comment: Hard to tell. Do you have any in managed code being used? Say ghostscript or some pdf, or maybe some database such as sqlite or jet/ Access? So this could be a x32 vs x64 bit issue.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/